# pgfplots point meta using luatex

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

I am trying to make a plot and color the points according to a third column using `only marks, point meta=\thisrow{Lz\N}` in `addplot`.

I get the error-Log entry:

```
Package pgfplots info on input line 1: Using 'lua backend=false' for plot 0 
(type 'pgfplothandlerdiscard'): point meta choice does not support LUA.
```

Is there any way around it? I prefer luatex due to the memory-requirements of the document I am currently working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely continue to use `luatex` and benefit from the memory requirements.

The informational message means that the plot in question fails to benefit from *speed* improvements of `lua backend`. But you do not need them.

So: simply ignore this message and continue as usual.

Comment: Are you sure we still benefit of the memory benefits of LuaLatex when we get this type of error?
I'm personally combining the error of this question and `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].`.
I prefer to be sure in order not to search in a wrong direction (it may be something else causing the error).

Comment: Yes, lua has a considerably simpler and better memory management than pdftex, so my answer is correct. However, there are different kinds of memory limits, and the "parameter stack size" is still limited in lua. Your error message is unrelated to this question and its answe; please file a separate question such that we can help you analyze the issue.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this important point to me. My issue was probably caused by incorrectly used commands and your answer allowed me to better direct my researches (ie not trying to extend capacity but to correct what causes the excess).